# What does the alt tag mean in HTML

Tags: html

I am just learning HTML. I have a confusion on using image and alt in learning HTML. When I use alt it doesn't go to the alt image.

```
<img src="w3schools.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" width="104" height="142">
```

When I try to use my own example, or image, it doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-alt

Comment: `Alt` tag which also stands for `alternative text` is a string which shows up in case the Image is not found in the specified location. Downvoting because it was a readily available info on Google search.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows zero research effort.

Comment: Question would've been easily answered if you had spent the time to type in three words into a Google search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **alt** attribute specifies an alternate text for the image, if it cannot be displayed.
The alt attribute is required in HTML4 and the page will not be valid without it.

Checkout at this link an example: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uz6od66u/1/).

```
<img src="http://www.1341234123412312/ic_mountain.jpg" alt="Image not found" style="width:200px;height:128px"/>
```

Comment: Kinda required. Some exceptions, and still in dispute: http://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2011/04/html5-accessibility-chops-the-alt-decision/

Answer (score 3):

`alt` isn't a tag, [it's an attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp).  It doesn't specify an alternate *image*, it defines the alternate *text* of an image if it cannot be displayed.  In most cases it's used as hover-over text.

Answer (score 2):

Like henriquedsg89 mentioned the alt ATTRIBUTE is used to display alternate text. An example of it's purpose would be if a blind person can't see the photos. Instead the browser will read the alt attribute out loud.

Answer (score 0):

alt is attribute, and used to display the image description. if image is not displayed because of some case.

```html
<img src="/img.jpg" alt="Image not found">
```